# WBR tag breaks arrow navigation in contenteditable div (Safari)

Tags: html, safari, contenteditable, wbr

When I try to move the caret with right arrow key on Safari, it gets stuck in the place where WBR tag is located.

It looks like a bug of Safari-browser, but are there any workarounds for this?

Code sample:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Div <wbr />with<wbr /> wbrs</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xkuqecy1/

Comment: Same for me (Safari 12.0.2), looks like a bug.